# iOS - modifying variables on website to eventually parse data

Tags: php, ios, asp.net, authentication

I want to make an app for this website: https://my.iusd.org/LoginParent.aspx

I wanted someone to just list the steps that I need to take to make an app that will let the user enter a username, password on the iDevice, and then pass those variables from the iDevice to that site ,so that if the authentication is correct, I can parse the data once the user logs in to show his or her grades.

If I need to make a separate php script to modify/pass variables to the site, how can I run the script for free without having to manage a server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, if I need to manage a server, is there a way to do it for free...aka Parse, Google Drive, anything?

Comment: I tried to pass variables to the url...cant find out how to do it....and I've also tried using this parser: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/    to modify the variables...I just don't know how to run it on a server for free for others to use after I make it

Comment: The website may not support passing data in remotely. Also running that PHP script and concocting an iOS app from scratch are completely different methods of approaching the problem. If you run the PHP script on a server you still need some sort of interaction in the iOS app to work with the website. It may be simpler to simply display the original website in the iOS app.

Also, it appears there is already an iOS app for this: https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/gradecheck/id598143684?mt=8

Comment: how could of the person who made the app have approached the problem? I want to make this app because the app hasn't been updated to the newest update of the website, and the interface is still ios5/6 style

Comment: That is probably a question best asked of the developer.

Comment: Can you tell me how I could make this work if I managed to get a server to run the php script?

Comment: I'm not sure how getting the PHP script running furthers your cause of wanting an iOS app to check grades. The PHP script would still run on a server, much as the existing website does.

Comment: The underlying system (Aeries) may have an API that your iOS app could call http://www.aeries.com/blog/plugging-into-aeries---the-aeries-api-is-now-available

Comment: The API is useless to me as it is meant for districts and also doesn't let you check grades. Can you please tell me a methodical approach I can take to take strings for an ios app, pass it to the variables on the website, and then parse the data?????